# Delphi DMVC Mapping an Object holding a TList<string> to JSONObjectString

Tags: delphi, objectmapper

I've got an Object I'd like to map to a JSON string with the DMVC-Framework's object mapper with the Delphi Berlin Starter Edition.

```
TListThing = class
  private
    FList : TList<string>;
  public
    property List : TList<String> read FList write FList;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;
  end;
```

But when I call `Mapper.ObjectToJSONObjectString(ListThing)` I get an invalid typecast, when the Mapper hits the List property.
Setting the attribute `[MapperListOf(string)]` List propetry crashes too. Does anyone have a solution for that or is this even a case for a bug report for the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, this version of the framework mapper that does not support filling niether **TList** nor **TStringList**. It works fine though with TObjectList, where AClass is nothing but a wrapper for your strings.

See description here: https://danieleteti.gitbooks.io/delphimvcframework/content/chapterrenders.html

```
[MapperListOf(TNested)]
  property NestedList: TObjectList<TNested> read FNestedList write  SetNestedList;
```

> For serialization and deserialization nested objects and object lists
>   must be created. But can be freed at runtime as we can see further
>   down.

Comment: You were right about the serialization of a TList<string>. On a sidenote:  `Mapper.JSONObjectStringToObject` actually fills a TList<string> properly.